# How to play and pause music in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have background music in my game. I tried to make a method to play and pause the music.

My app crashes when I press on the play/pause music button.

I don't understand why its not working.

**The method in the Main Scene: (Edited)**

```
var SoundOnOff = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "MusicOn.png")

if (SoundOnOff.containsPoint(location)) {


        if BackgroundMusic.sharedHelper.isMuted() {
        //BackgroundMusic.sharedHelper.mute()
        BackgroundMusic.sharedHelper.pause()
        self.SoundOnOff.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"MusicOff.png")
        print("Music Off!")
        }
        else {
        //BackgroundMusic.sharedHelper.unmute()
        BackgroundMusic.sharedHelper.resume()
        self.SoundOnOff.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"MusicOn.png")
        print("Music On!")
        }
    }
```

**BackgroundMusic Class (Edited)**

```
import AVFoundation

class BackgroundMusic: NSObject {


  internal let localDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
  static let sharedHelper = BackgroundMusic()
    var BgMusic: AVAudioPlayer?

    /// Keys
    internal struct Key {
        static let muted = "MusicMuteState"
    }


    override init() {
        super.init()
        print("Music helper init")
        playBackgroundMusic()

        if isMuted() {
            mute()
        }
    }

    func playBackgroundMusic() {
        let aSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Secrets of the Schoolyard", ofType: "mp3")!)
        do {
            BgMusic = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:aSound)
            BgMusic!.numberOfLoops = -1
            BgMusic!.prepareToPlay()
            BgMusic!.play()
        } catch {
            print("Cannot play the file")
        }
    }

    func mute() {
        BgMusic!.volume = 0
        localDefaults.setBool(true, forKey: Key.muted)
    }

    /// Unmute
    func unmute() {
        BgMusic!.volume = 1
        localDefaults.setBool(false, forKey: Key.muted)
    }

    // Check mute state
    func isMuted() -> Bool {
        if localDefaults.boolForKey(Key.muted) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace every occurence of force-unwrapping with safe-unwrapping (using `if let ... else ...` for example) and catch the actual error instead of just printing a canned sentence. You will then be able to find the bug and fix it.

Comment: i checked that and i found problem with the line : BackgroundMusic.sharedHelper.playing

Comment: if you are targetting iOS 9 only,  you have the option to use SKAudioNode

Comment: I want to use in AVFoundation for iOS 8 later

Answer (score 0):

Your class is a subclass of AVAudioPlayer but you're not actually using your own instance to play the music.   When you use BackgroundMusic.sharedHelper.playing, you're referencing an instance of your class, not the BgMusic player that is actually playing.  Since your class hasn't been initialized with any sound file, I presume that it cannot properly process .playing

Answer (score -1):

I recently answered a similar question. I am also using my own helper for music which is similar to yours. There is a few things that you should do different in your helper.

[On and off music/sfx for sprite kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34544088/on-and-off-music-sfx-for-sprite-kit/34557092#34557092)

GitHub: https://github.com/crashoverride777/Swift2-SpriteKit-Music-Helper

Comment: why not. Im using this helper, its defiantly working. Check my github project https://github.com/crashoverride777/Swift2-SpriteKit-Music-Helper

Comment: Did you fix your issue? Can you mark my answer as correct if so please